# Mongo DB 3.2 ttl using c# wrapper

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I'm not having any luck to get documents to expire using the ttl feature using the c# wrapper.

My code:

```
string j = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xnode, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
            var b = BsonDocument.Parse(j);
            var date = new DateTime(2016,8,4,16,25,0,0);
            var bdate = new BsonElement("expiresAt", date.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o"));
            b.Add(bdate);
            _collection.InsertOneAsync(b);
```

The documents are inserted correctly with the expiresAt element looking like this: "expiresAt" : "2016-08-04T18:38:00.0000000Z"

I've created an index using the documentation:  db.testc.createIndex( { "expireAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 } )

The time comes and goes but the documents are never removed from the collection.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out after looking at the code and the data in the collection.  The BSon data type of date was not being assigned correctly.  This is because this line was incorrect:

```
var bdate = new BsonElement("expiresAt", date.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o"));
```

Should be:

```
var bdate = new BsonElement("expiresAt", date.ToUniversalTime());
```